# How to use same Edittext as two different in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext, settext

Hi I am a Beginner in Android Development. I want to display data from xampp (phpmyadmin) in EditText if EditText value
is not equal to ""(data from xampp!="")  and if equal to ""(data from xampp==""), I want the user to type the value .{if the value is displayed it should not editable for user} I tried if..else

`

```
if(DepartStation_txt!=""){
   DS.setText(DepartStation_txt);
   DS.setEnabled(false);
}else {
    DS.setText("Enter the Value");
    DS.setEnabled(true);
}
```

`
where DS is EditText DS=

```
(EditText) findViewById(R.id.DS);
```

in onCreate

Any functions that does this job and reason for this not working

Answer (score -1):

Simply use methods of `String` class to compare strings. Now first of all you need to read text from `EditText` control then you check if the string you want presents. For your case the sample code would be:

```java
String DepartStation_txt;  // I don't know where do you get it from
String currentString = DS.getText().toString; // Read the current string first, if any 

if(currentString != null) {
    if(!currentString.isEqual(DepartStation_txt)) {
        DS.setText(DepartStation_txt);
        DS.setEnebled(false);
    }
    else {
        DS.setHint("Enter the value");
        DS.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
else {
// EditText has no string at all, user has to enter the value??
    DS.setHint("Enter the value");
    DS.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Note that I used the `setHint` method instead of the `setText` method since it is more suitable to instruct the users.